# FreeTDS para conectar a SQL Server

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Tengo 2 servidores, un servidor web *Fedora 28* donde tengo entre otras cosas, un formulario que quiero conectar con mi otro servidor *Windows 2008 server* que contiene el *SQL Server 2012*. Ambos están en la misma red.

He intentado instalando de mil formas los drivers que ofrece microsoft, y siempre daban fallos. Entonces fue cuando encontré **FreeTDS**. Según he leído, conecta perfectamente con las bases de *SQL Server* desde *Linux*, lo único... Es que no sé cómo seguir.

Primero especifiqué el host en */etc/freetds.conf*

```
# A typical Sybase server
[egServer50]
    host = 192.168.9.10
        port = 1433
        tds version = 5.0

# A typical Microsoft server
[egServer70]
    host = 192.168.9.10
        port = 1433
        tds version = 7.0
```

Luego en el archivo */etc/odbcinst.ini* tengo que especificar donde se encuentran los drives. Lo siguiente ya se encontraba escrito, no sé si tengo que añadir algo más.

```
[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.4.so.2.1
UsageCount=1

[ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-13.1.so.9.2
UsageCount=1
```

Por último en */etc/odbc.ini*

```
Description = mssql server

Driver = FreeTDS

Database = logytel

ServerName = mssql

TDS_Version = 7.3
```

**conexion.php**

```
<?php 
try {

        $pdo = new PDO('odbc:mssql', 'user', 'pass');

 }

 catch(Exception $e){

        echo $e->getMessage();

 }
?>
```

Cuando trato de conectarme vía web al archivo **conexión.php**, me sale un mensaje diciendo

> *Could not find driver*

Sigo teniendo los drivers de microsoft (**sqlsrv.so**, **pdo_sqlsrv.so**) instalados, y en el **php.ini** tengo

```
extension=sqlsrv.so
extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so
```

Y si ejecuto el *php* con el comando `php conexion.php`, me sale este mensaje

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   'pdo_sqlsrv.so' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_sqlsrv.so
>   (/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_sqlsrv.so: undefined symbol:
>   php_pdo_register_driver), /usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_sqlsrv.so.so
>   (/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_sqlsrv.so.so: cannot open shared object
>   file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que la extensión pdo_sqlsrv depende de que haya sido cargada primero la extensión pdo.

Lo aconsejable sería procurar que el orden de los .ini de las extensiones fuera el correcto. Por ejemplo: si la extensión de pdo es `10-pdo.ini`, crear un fichero llamado `20-sqlsrv.ini` en el que agregas las dos líneas de extension.

Por otro lado, parece que el driver de conexión es `sqlsrv:server` y no `odbc:mssql`

Comment: Ya tengo las extensiones de PHP instaladas. Estoy usando PHP 7.2.18. Que yo sepa, no tengo más versiones instaladas, pero de todas formas, ¿cómo se miraría eso?

Comment: Depende de tu distribución de linux, en `/usr/bin` puedes encontrar si tienes uno o varios binarios de PHP. ¿Has probado a lanzar esos comandos?

Comment: En /usr/lib no hay nada de php, en cambio en /usr/lib64 esto es lo único que pone php: 
`php,
php-zts`

Y sí, instalé las extensiones con esos comandos. 
En php -m sale la extensión `sqlsrv`, pero no la de `pdo_sqlsrv`

Comment: `/usr/bin`, no `/usr/lib` :-). De todos modos, puede entonces que te falle por no tener `pdo_sqlsrv`. ¿Has probado a instalarla como te menciono en la respuesta?

Comment: Disculpa, leí mal. En /usr/bin están estos ficheros que contiene 'php':
 `php
 php-cgi
 php-config
 phpize
 php-phpmyadmin-sql-parser-highlight-query
 php-phpmyadmin-sql-parser-lint-query`
Sí, está instalado tal cual. En la pregunta está el mensaje que me sale respecto a pdo_sqlsrv

Comment: ¿Y tienes instalada la extensión de `pdo`?

Comment: Ojo porque `mysqli` y `pdo` son dos extensiones diferentes. Tendrías que confirmar si tienes instalada y habilitada la extensión `pdo`

Comment: php -m `PDO,
pdo_mysql,
pdo_pgsql,
pdo_sqlite
`

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102407/discussion-between-dev-nix-and-lucia).

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta, para que quede de referencia